# How to display my reference image in Wireframe mode

Tags: materials, image, workflow, wireframe, viewlayers

I imported my reference via *Images as plane*. I can view them in material preview, but when i switched to wireframe mode I can't see my refernce images.

How can i fix that?

Two pics for proper demonstration of my problem.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is intended behavior. You can use _X-ray_ instead by pressing **Alt Z** to make objects partially transparent.

Comment: If you're using the image as a blueprint, I'd suggest using _Add Menu > Image > Background._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Add <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Empty > Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add image as reference. If you do that,you can see the image in any tab,wireframe/solid view or even rendered view.